# Getting instance of a class type in Angular 2 in a static method

Tags: angular

Is it possible to get an instance of a class from the dependency injector of Angular2, in a static method?

I'm creating a utility static class, and need to get an instance of the logger.

Something on these lines:

```
angular.injector.getInstance(LoggerFactory)
```